# Pandas: Replacing column values with ones as retrieved from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am stumbled upon a trivial problem in pandas. I have two dataframes. The first one, `df_1` is as follows

```
vendor_name     date            company_name     state
PERTH          is june 2019     Abc enterprise   Kentucky
Megan Ent      25-april-2019    Xyz Fincorp      Texas
```

The second one `df_2` contains the correct values for each column in `df_1`.

```
df_2
Field          wrong value     correct value
vendor_name    PERTH           Perth Enterprise
date           is              15   ## this means that is should be read as 15
company_name   Abc enterprise  ABC International Enterprise Inc.
```

In order to replace the values with correct ones in `df_1` (except `date` field) I am using `pandas.loc` method. Below is the code snippet

```
vend = df_1['vendor_Name'].tolist()
comp = df_1['company_name'].tolist()
state = df_1['state'].tolist()

for i in vend:
   if df_2['wrong value'].str.contains(i):
      crct = df_2.loc[df_2['wrong value'] == i,'correct value'].tolist()
```

Similarly, for company and state I have followed the above way. 
However, the `crct` is returning a blank series. Ideally it should return

```
['Perth Enterprise','Abc International Enterprise Inc']
```

The next step would be to `replace` the respective field values by the above list.

With the above, I have three questions:

1. Why the above code is generating a blank list? What I am missing here?
2. How can I replace the respective fields using `df_1.replace` method?
3. What should be a correct approach to replace the portion of date in `df_1` by the correct one in `df_2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: when data has looping replacement(i.e overlaping keys and values), replacement on whole dataframe will fail. In this case, doing it column by column and `concat` them together. Finally, use `join` to adding any missing columns from `df1`:

```
df_replace = pd.concat([df1[k].replace(val, regex=True) for k, val in d.items()], axis=1).join(df1.state)
```

---

**Original**:
I tried your code in my interactive and it gives error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous` on `df_2['wrong value'].str.contains(i)`.

assume you have multiple vendor names, so the simple way is construct a dictionary from groupby of `df2` and use it with `df.replace` on `df1`.

```
d = {k: gp.set_index('wrong value')['correct value'].to_dict() 
               for k, gp in df2.groupby('Field')}

Out[64]:
{'company_name': {'Abc enterprise': 'ABC International Enterprise Inc. '},
 'date': {'is': '15'},
 'vendor_name': {'PERTH': 'Perth Enterprise'}}

df_replace = df1.replace(d, regex=True)    
print(df_replace)

In [68]:
        vendor_name           date                        company_name  \
0  Perth Enterprise   15 june 2019  ABC International Enterprise Inc.
1         Megan Ent  25-april-2019                         Xyz Fincorp

      state
0  Kentucky
1     Texas
```

---

**Note**: your sample `df2` has only value for vendor `PERTH`, so it only replace first row. When you have all `vendor_names` in `df2`, it will replace them all in `df1`.

Comment: quite a smart one

Comment: However it is giving the error `ValueError: Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values`

Comment: @pythondumb: it seems your data has looping replacement. I.e it is `A` replacing by `B` and later on another rows `B` replacing by `A`. It is the reason for that error. Try this line: `df_replace = pd.concat([df1[k].replace(val, regex=True) for k, val in d.items()], axis=1).join(df1.state)`

Comment: Do I need `join(df1.state)`? The resultant `df` is not having all the columns as `df_1`. However, that possibly can be managed using `pd.concat` with missed out columns in `df_1`. What is your suggestion? Also please edit your answer.

Comment: @pythondumb: `join` to add missing columns of `df1` to the final `df`. If there are other columns besides `df1.state`, just join on slicing of those columns such as `.join(df1[['state', 'colA', 'colB']]`.   Of course, you may use `pd.concat` to achieve it. I don't know whether it works with your real data, so I wait for you confirmation before adding this solution to the answer. Does it work?

Comment: Hi Andy, yes it works. You may edit the answer. Meanwhile, can you throw some light on how to replace only `is` part in the date with `15` ? In your solution, it is replacing the whole string i.e. `is june 2019` by 15. Thanks.

Comment: @pythondumb: I edited the answer. The `regex=True` in the command already handled replacement only `is` part. It either replaces only `is` or skip. I tested again with key-value `{'is': 15}`, it correctly replace only `is`. Perhaps, dictionary `d` has something like `{'is june 2019': 15}` so it causes the replacement of whole string instead of only `is` ?

Comment: No the dictionary `d` has key `is` and corresponding value is 15. Problem is in `replace`...it is replacing the whole.

Comment: @pythondumb: could you create me a sample `df` for this replace whole string case? Your sample in the question got `is` replaced correctly by `15`. Therefore I can't reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following *replace* function:

```
def repl(row):
    fld = row.Field
    v1 = row['wrong value']
    v2 = row['correct value']
    updInd = df_1[df_1[fld].str.contains(v1)].index
    df_1.loc[updInd, fld] = df_1.loc[updInd, fld]\
        .str.replace(re.escape(v1), v2)
```

Then call it for each row in *df_2*:

```
for _, row in df_2.iterrows():
    repl(row)
```

Note that *str.replace* alone does not require to *import re* (*Pandas*
imports it under the hood).
But in the above function *re.escape* is called explicitely, from our code,
hence *import re* is required.

Comment: I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` Besides, your last line i.e. `df_1[fld].str.contains(v1)` is not clear to me. In `df_2` there are multiple fields and the above line tends to capture only the first one as there is no `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I made some mistake copying the code. Now I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is to iterate over the first dataframe and then replace the wrong values :

```
Result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df1)):
    vendor_name = df1.iloc[i]['vendor_name']
    date = df1.iloc[i]['date']
    company_name = df1.iloc[i]['company_name']

    if vendor_name in df2['wrong value'].values:
        vendor_name = df2.loc[df2['wrong value'] == vendor_name]['correct value'].values[0]
    if company_name in df2['wrong value'].values:
        company_name = df2.loc[df2['wrong value'] == company_name]['correct value'].values[0]

    new_row = {'vendor_name':[vendor_name],'date':[date],'company_name':[company_name]}    
    new_row = pd.DataFrame(new_row,columns=['vendor_name','date','company_name'])
    Result = Result.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't change the `date`in `df_1`. I had added an extra line `if date in df_2['wrong value'].values:                                                                              
           date = df_2.loc[df_2['wrong value'] == date,'correct value']`but this seems not working